# Entity Framework Configuration Issues

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I need to let each SimCompare have two lists of SimCompareSimulationTypes.

SimCompare:

```
public class SimCompare : Report
{
    public string LeftGraphName { get; set; }
    public int? LeftConsolidationId { get; set; }
    public int LeftAsOfDateOffset { get; set; }
    public virtual Consolidation LeftConsolidation { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<SimCompareSimulationType> SimCompareLeftSimulations { get; set; }


    public string RightGraphName { get; set; }
    public int? RightConsolidationId { get; set; }
    public int RightAsOfDateOffset { get; set; }
    public virtual Consolidation RightConsolidation { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<SimCompareSimulationType> SimCompareRightSimulations { get; set; }

    public bool IsQuarterly { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<SimCompareScenarioType> SimCompareScenarioTypes { get; set; }
}
```

SimCompareSimulationType:

```
    public class SimCompareSimulationType
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int SimCompareId { get; set; }
    public virtual SimCompare SimCompare { get; set; }
    public int SimulationTypeId { get; set; }
    public virtual SimulationType SimulationType { get; set; }
    public int Priority { get; set; }
}
```

When it tries to create a SimCompare neither of the collections get created. There's a mapping file that's all commented out and that I have no clue what to do with.

```
//HasRequired(l => l.LeftSimCompareSimulationTypes)
        //    .WithMany()
        //    .HasForeignKey(t => t.LeftSimCompareSimulationTypeId)
        //    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
//HasRequired(l => l.RightSimCompareSimulationTypes)
        //    .WithMany()
        //    .HasForeignKey(t => t.RightSimCompareSimulationTypeId)
        //    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

Any help on this? I have very little understanding of how this should work.

Answer (score 0):

In lamemans terms, the configuration specifies how the entities translate to db tables.
So in order for `SimCompare` to have a collection of `SimCompareSimulationTypes` you'll need to update the configuration.

When using code first you normally need to manually create the configs, defaults get generated, but i often find that they don't work for 100% of my requirements.

> Just out of interest, have you tried running the commented out code?

```
this.HasRequired(l => l.LeftSimCompareSimulationTypes)
    .WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey(t => t.LeftSimCompareSimulationTypeId)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

Example of one of our configs.

```
public class SomeConfiguration: EntityTypeConfiguration<Some>
{

      public SomeConfiguration()
      {
          // Property/column will have a max of 10 & will be required
          this.Property(o => o.Code).HasMaxLength(10).IsRequired();

          // Property/column will have a max of 50 & will be required
          this.Property(o => o.Name).HasMaxLength(50).IsRequired().IsUnicode(false);

          // will be nullable in the db, with a foreign key of ExchangeID
          this.HasOptional(o => o.Exchange).WithMany().HasForeignKey(o => o.ExchangeId).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);    
      }
}
```

Comment: so should I just uncomment the code there? have the two blocks which look like they're declaring two foreign keys?